# Unable to send email using Flask_mail. Connection refused

Tags: python, python-3.x

[**Can anyone tell me why i keep getting this error?
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJyli.png)

Comment: Have you tried using port `587` too?

Comment: Error messages are *text* and should included as such, refrain from posting images unless absolutely necessary as images will not be picked-up when others search for this same issue, etc.

Comment: yes ive tried to use both 465 and 587